# Trying to implement Dijsktra in Java using priority queue and using hash map for decrease key

Tags: java, hashmap, priority-queue, dijkstra

Full Disclosure - I am doing this exercise to solve this problem on Leetcode - https://leetcode.com/problems/network-delay-time/

I find that this code is not working for certain test cases. I have been trying to debug this for a few hours havent had any luck. Can anyone help the bug in this code.

```
// this has a bug which I dont know how to find
  public int networkDelayTime(int[][] times, int N, int K) {
    Map<Integer, Map<Integer,Integer>> adjListWithDistance = new HashMap<>();
    // using this distance Map from K as comparator in priority queue
    Map<Integer, Integer> dMapFromK = new HashMap<>();

    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((k1,k2) -> dMapFromK.get(k1) - dMapFromK.get(k2));
    HashSet<Integer> v = new HashSet<>();


    for(int i = 0; i < times.length; i++){
      int source = times[i][0];
      int dest = times[i][1];
      int dist = times[i][2];

      adjListWithDistance.putIfAbsent(source, new HashMap<>());
      adjListWithDistance.get(source).put(dest, dist);
      //if(source == K){
      //    dMapFromK.put(dest, dist);
      //    pq.add(dest);
      // }
    }

    // distance from K to K is 0
    dMapFromK.put(K, 0);
    pq.add(K);

    // we have already added all nodes from K to PQ, so we dont need to process K again
    //v.add(K);


    //System.out.println(adjListWithDistance);
    //System.out.println(dMapFromK);
    int res = 0;
    while(!pq.isEmpty()){
      int fromNode = pq.poll();
      if(v.contains(fromNode)) continue;
      v.add(fromNode);
      int curDist = dMapFromK.get(fromNode);
      res = curDist;
      //System.out.println("current node - " + fromNode);
      if(!adjListWithDistance.containsKey(fromNode)) {
        continue;
      }
      for(Integer toNode: adjListWithDistance.get(fromNode).keySet()){
        // BIG BUGGGGG, adding the below line is also causing a bug , not sure why
        if(v.contains(toNode)) continue;
        int toNodeDist = adjListWithDistance.get(fromNode).get(toNode);
        if(dMapFromK.containsKey(toNode) && dMapFromK.get(toNode) <= curDist + toNodeDist){
          continue;
        }else {
          if(!dMapFromK.containsKey(toNode)){
            dMapFromK.put(toNode, curDist + toNodeDist);

            // need to add map entry first before adding to priority queue else it throws an exception
            pq.offer(toNode);
          }else{
            dMapFromK.put(toNode, curDist + toNodeDist);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println(adjListWithDistance);
    System.out.println(dMapFromK);
    if(dMapFromK.keySet().size() != N)
      return -1;
    //return res;
    return Collections.max(dMapFromK.values());
  }
```

TLDR: This implementation of Dijsktra is not correct and doesn't return the shortest path for certain nodes for certain test cases. I'm not sure why, and I need help debugging what mistake I am making.

Comment: Would you mind summarizing the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Of course, this implementation of Dijsktra is not correct and doesn't return the shortest path for certain nodes. I'm not sure why, and I need help debugging what mistake I am making.

Comment: I meant a summary of the Leetcode problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost the same, will pass through:

```
public final class Solution {
    public static final int networkDelayTime(
        final int[][] times,
        int n,
        final int k
    ) {
        Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();

        for (final int[] node : times) {
            graph.putIfAbsent(node[0], new HashMap<>());
            graph.get(node[0]).put(node[1], node[2]);
        }

        Queue<int[]> queue = new PriorityQueue<>((a, b) -> (a[0] - b[0]));
        queue.add(new int[] {0, k});
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n + 1];
        int total = 0;

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            int[] curr = queue.remove();
            int currNode = curr[1];
            int currTime = curr[0];

            if (visited[currNode]) {
                continue;
            }

            visited[currNode] = true;
            total = currTime;
            n--;

            if (graph.containsKey(currNode)) {
                for (final int next : graph.get(currNode).keySet()) {
                    queue.add(new int[] {currTime + graph.get(currNode).get(next), next});
                }
            }
        }

        return n == 0 ? total : -1;
    }
}
```

Here is a Python version using heap, if you'd be interested:

```
from typing import List
import heapq
from collections import defaultdict

class Solution:
    def networkDelayTime(self, times: List[List[int]], n, k) -> int:
        queue = [(0, k)]
        graph = collections.defaultdict(list)
        memo = {}

        for u_node, v_node, time in times:
            graph[u_node].append((v_node, time))

        while queue:
            time, node = heapq.heappop(queue)
            if node not in memo:
                memo[node] = time
                for v_node, v_time in graph[node]:
                    heapq.heappush(queue, (time + v_time, v_node))
        return max(memo.values()) if len(memo) == n else -1
```

In C++, we'd just use a fast integer type:

```
// The following block might trivially improve the exec time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);
    std::cout.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


#define MAX INT_MAX
using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;

static const struct Solution {
    static const int networkDelayTime(
        const std::vector<vector<int>>& times, 
        int n, 
        const int k
    ) {
        std::vector<ValueType> distances(n + 1, MAX);
        distances[k] = 0;

        for (ValueType index = 0; index < n; index++) {
            for (const auto& time : times) {
                const ValueType u_node = time[0];
                const ValueType v_node = time[1];
                const ValueType uv_weight = time[2];

                if (distances[u_node] != MAX && distances[v_node] > distances[u_node] + uv_weight) {
                    distances[v_node] = distances[u_node] + uv_weight;
                }
            }
        }

        ValueType total_time = 0;

        for (auto index = 1; index <= n; index++) {
            total_time = std::max(total_time, distances[index]);
        }

        return total_time == MAX ? -1 : total_time;
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/network-delay-time/discuss) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, I had seen this in the discussion board. I find that this priority queue is very inefficient since we keep adding duplicate vertices with different weights. Even though it is logn to get extract-min, there is memory cost to adding all this duplicate nodes.  That's why I was using the distance map keyset as  priority queue elements to avoid this duplicate problem. Not sure why it is not updating edge distance for certain nodes in very large test cases.